# how can I promote an app from alpha to beta on play store and use a different database?

Tags: android, google-play

I upload an APK (versionCode=1) to play store to alpha and test it. Then if its okay I'd like to promote it to beta and eventually prod. While its in beta, I'll probably upload a new APK to alpha (versionCode=2).

I'd alpha apps to use a staging database URL, and when promoted to beta I'd like them to use the production URL.

Is there some variable on the play store environment I can access at run time so I can set the URL programmatically?

Thx